# Listen to Formik values changes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, formik

I've a formik form in a component that I'd want to reuse. In order to do that I need to listen to the form values changes in order to call two functions, `getFormValues` and `getFormErrors`, that will be passed by the parent component:

```
import React from "react";
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { Formik } from 'formik';
import CheckBox from "@react-native-community/checkbox";
import { Text, TextInput } from "react-native";
import { errorStyle } from "../../styles/form.styles";

export default function UserCredentialForm({getFormValues, getFormErrors}) {
  const formSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string().email()
      .required('Required'),
    password: Yup.string()
      .test('lenght', 'min 5chr max 10chr', (val = '') => val.length > 4 && val.length < 11)
      .required('Required'),
  });
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    form: {
      email: '',
      password: '',
    }
  });
  const formRef = React.useRef({} as any);

  React.useEffect(() => {    
    console.log('formref', formRef.current.values);
    getFormValues(formRef.current.values);
    getFormErrors(formRef.current.errors);
  }, [formRef.current.values, formRef.current.errors]);

  return (
    <Formik innerRef={formRef} validationSchema={formSchema} initialValues={state.form} onSubmit={() => {}}>
      {({ handleChange, values, touched, errors }) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          {errors.password && touched.password ? <Text>{errors.email}</Text> : null}
          <TextInput
            style={errors.email && touched.email ? errorStyle.input : null}
            keyboardType='email-address'
            onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
            value={values.email}
            placeholder="email"
          />
          {errors.password && touched.password ? <Text>{errors.password}</Text> : null}
          <TextInput
            style={errors.password && touched.password ? errorStyle.input : null}
            onChangeText={handleChange('password')}
            value={values.password}
            placeholder="password"
            secureTextEntry={true}
          />
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
}
```

As you can see I'm using `useEffect` hooks linked to the form ref values, but it get called only once at form first render. What am I missing?
How can I subscribe to all values changes?

Answer (score 5):

Got a solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56269090/752636

I need to move my hooks inside the form

```
<Formik
    initialValues={initialValues}
    ...
  >
    {props => {
      getFormErrors(props.errors); // store values in state 'formValues'
      getFormValues(props.values); // or use any function to get values like this
      return (
        <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `useFormikContext` hook to get values. You shouldn't be using ref inside useEffect because mutating the `ref.current` won't trigger a render.
Here is the implementation of `useFormikContext` hook

https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormikContext

Comment: useFormikContext works from parento to child, I need something to comunicate from child to parent